# Repeating a function while holding down a key

Tags: python, keyboard

I'm trying to make a script where, when holding down ALT, the `shoot()` function is repeated. And upon releasing the key, waiting for it to be held again.
This is my code

```
if keyboard.is_pressed('alt'):
    shoot()
```

I know this seems like a dumb question,but I've only started about a week ago using python.

Comment: What kind of context do you want to use this in?

Answer (score 0):

Here is some sample i put explanation in comments

```
import keyboard
import time

def shoot():
    # do something
    print('Fire the enemy')

while True:  # loop forever until escape key
    if keyboard.is_pressed('alt'):
        shoot()

    if keyboard.is_pressed('esc'):  # quit loop
        print('quit')
        break

    time.sleep(0.1) # delay to prevent processor abuse
```